# How to check if canvas objects overlap each other

Tags: html, object, canvas, overlap

I'm trying to check if two objects (e.g. a rectangle and a triangle) on a HTML5 canvas are overlapping each other.

Currently I can only check that by looking at the screen (having set globalCompositeOperation='lighter').

My first idea would have been to scan all over the canvas if the "lighter" (compare code snippet above) color exists in the canvas. But therefor I would have to look at every single pixel which was rather costly for what I need.

Is there a (better) alternative to automatically check if they are overlapping?

Best regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The site below explains how to use the Separating Axis Theorem to determine if two convex shapes overlap.

http://www.codezealot.org/archives/55

To use this you will need to know the coordinate data used in contstructing the shapes.

Comment: Okay, looks confusing at first sight.
I will see if that solves my problem. Thanks!

Comment: Oops! That page can’t be found.